# jquery events on table cells with very large tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a large table with circa 10,000 cells which is in the form of an X-Y scrolling grid somewhat like a spreadsheet (approx 90 columns x 100 rows). This uses the Datatables jquery plugin with the fixedColumns extension to lock the header row and leftmost column in place and then scroll cells within a fixed size window.

This works, but the snag is that the load and render time of the table becomes extremely slow if I use jquery to attach event handlers to all cells (via the td's) so that clicking on a cell allows the content to be edited. This is the whole point of the exercise, so I need a smarter solution to achieve this result.

I can attach events to the whole table or even each row to catch an event without a significant time penalty, but then how to find out which cell has been clicked?

I did think of trying something based on mouse position when the click event was generated relative to the table origin, but the range of cells visible in the viewport is only a small part of the sheet (about 180-190 at a time), so the X/Y scroll bars are significant too in any calculation.

Anyone have suggestions of other/better approaches that may work?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', 'table.your_table td', function() {});`.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't attach event handlers to the `document` element as this will have a performance impact. The handler should be attached as close to the elements as possible in the hierarchical sense.

Comment: Everyone came back with (approximately) the right answer! .on solves the problem - I just attach to the table->tbody and filter on td and it works fine. (remind myself to RTFM!)

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the event handler to the table element. That is, by taking advantage of how JS bubbles up events through each parent element, instead of create a new handler for each element you can simply create one on the `<table>` element as per the below fiddle. This is called event delegation.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/bsf9a8w1/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $table = $('#table');
    $table.on('click', 'td', function() {
        // 'this' is your cell element
        console.log($(this));     
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How are you attaching the event handlers?  On each cell (TD) individually?

You should think about attaching the event handlers to one of the parent elements (events bubble up to the parent, unless stopPropagation is called).

So something like this would work as well:

```
$(table).on('td', 'click', eventHandler);
```

Which would attach the event to the table, and return any time a cell was clicked on.  Which should be much faster for you, and have no loss in functionality.

Hope that helps.